# Check if user is already logged in doesn't work

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to modify the code for my login screen to check if the user is already logged in before showing the login screen. If the user is already logged in, you want to redirect them to the MapsActivity screen.

I am using firebase.

I've tried using Firebase Authentication, but I couldn't get it to work.

This code is Login.java

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseAuth authProfile;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("URL");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        final EditText username = findViewById(R.id.username);
        final EditText password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        final Button loginBtn = findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
        final TextView registerNowBtn = findViewById(R.id.registerNowBtn);

        authProfile = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final String usernameTxt=username.getText().toString();
                final String passwordTxt=password.getText().toString();

                if(usernameTxt.isEmpty() || passwordTxt.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Please enter username or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    databaseReference.child("users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            if(snapshot.hasChild(usernameTxt)){
                                final String getPassword = snapshot.child(usernameTxt).child("password").getValue(String.class);
                                if(getPassword != null && getPassword.equals(passwordTxt)){
                                    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = authProfile.getCurrentUser();
                                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, MapsActivity.class));
                                    finish();
                                }
                                else{
                                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Wrong Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                            else{
                                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Wrong Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        registerNowBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Register.class));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(authProfile.getCurrentUser()!=null){
            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, MapsActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I couldn't get it to work" is hard to help with. I recommend [debugging the code](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) you shared locally, and then telling is the results of that. So: If you [set a breakpoint](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#breakPoints) on each line of the code you shared, [run the code in a debugger], and then [check the value of each variable](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#variablesAndWatches) on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.